# What causes this color shift?

Tags: color, compression

Below are the original image and a JPEG encoded/decoded image. To my untrained eyes, cyan becomes yellow, yellow becomes magenta, and magenta becomes cyan. Obviously there's a problem with the encoding and/or decoding, but I'd appreciate a more specific answer, along the lines of: "The image was encoded in X [color space], but was decoded in Y." Thank you.

[image: original]

[image: JPEG]

Comment: It looks to me like the RGB data from the first image is being interpreted as Y'CbCr data in the second image. Since the Y' value goes from -0.5 to +0.5, 0.0 is a greenish color rather than black.

Comment: You write that you want a _specific_ answer, but I think that is going to be difficult if you don't give any information about the tools you used to convert it, where you find the image, etc.